# Adicionar itens no array sem criar um novo nível

Tags: php, array

Tenho a seguinte rotina que gera um array para mim:

```
$tipo = "V";

if($tipo == "V"){
    $addonTypeSuccess = ["size" => 10, "option" => 'classic', "type" => "volume"];
}

$arrayAWSAgregado[] = array(
    "product_alias" => 'teste',
    "months" => 1,
    $addonTypeSuccess
);

$arrayAWS[] = array(
    "product_alias" => 'teste',
    "os" => 'linux',
    "months" => 1,
    "addons" => $arrayAWSAgregado
);

$dataAssinatura = array(
    'email' => 'teste@teste.com.br', 
    'order_id' => 29292, 
    'products' => $arrayAWS
);
```

Isso gera o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [email] => teste@teste.com.br
    [order_id] => 29292
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_alias] => teste
                    [os] => linux
                    [months] => 1
                    [addons] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [product_alias] => teste
                                    [months] => 1
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [size] => 10
                                            [option] => classic
                                            [type] => volume
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Gostaria que o array [size],[option] e [type] não fossem colocados dentro de um array. Como posso fazer isso? Gostaria que estivessem no mesmo nível de [product_alias] e [months].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize **[array_merge](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php)** para mesclar dois ou mais arrays.

```
$arrayAWSAgregado[] = array_merge(array(
    "product_alias" => 'teste',
    "months" => 1
), $addonTypeSuccess);
```

Comment: PERFEITO! Muito obrigado! \